# Microsoft Power Automate - Hide body from response

Tags: power-automate, power-automate-custom-connector

I am trying to develop a custom connector in Microsoft Power Platform. Currently my connector have one action:

```yaml
paths:
  /Array_Find-Differences:
    post:
      description: Find items from one array that is not present in the second array
      operationId: post-array-find-differences
      summary: Array - Find Difference Between Two Arrays
      tags:
        - Array
      parameters:
        - name: array_Find-Difference-Definition
          in: body
          schema:
            $ref: '#/definitions/Array_Find-Difference-Definition'
          description: Provide an input array as well as an array to compare against.
          required: true
          x-ms-visibility: important
      consumes:
        - application/json
      produces:
        - application/json
      responses:
        '200':
          description: >-
            Returns a new array containing the values that are not present in
            the original array.
          examples:
            application/json: []
          schema:
            type: object
            properties:
              array:
                type: array
                items:
                  type: string
                  description: The new array containing different values.
                  title: Difference Array
                  x-ms-visibility: important
                description: array
definitions:
  Array_Find-Difference-Definition:
    type: object
    x-ms-visibility: important
    properties:
      array:
        type: string
      compare:
        type: string
    example:
      array:
        - 1
        - 2
        - 3
      compare:
        - 1
        - 2
        - 3
        - 4
```

As you can see in the response, I have only defined "Difference Array" as the output I want to show.

However, in the Power Automate workflow designer, I am presented with other options such as `array` and `body`.

How can I hide these?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In the UI you can set the visibility of each property when you import the Response 'from sample'. If you then click on the respective properties, you can change the visibility from there.

Does that fix your problem?